# Computing pseudo inverse of a matrix using sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

How should I compute the pseudo-inverse of a matrix using sympy (not using numpy, because the matrix has symbolic constants and I want the inverse also in symbolic). The normal `inv()` does not work for a non-square matrix in sympy. For example if `M = Matrix(2,3, [1,2,3,4,5,6]), pinv(M)` should give

```
-0.9444   0.4444
-0.1111   0.1111
 0.7222  -0.2222
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think since this is all symbolic it should be OK to use the text-book formulas taught in a linear algebra class (e.g. see the list of special cases in the Wikipedia article on the [Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse&oldid=540619506#Special_cases)). For numerical evaluation `pinv` uses the singular value decomposition (svd) instead.

You have linearly independent rows (full row rank), so you can use the formula for a 'right' inverse:

```
>>> import sympy as sy
>>> M = sy.Matrix(2,3, [1,2,3,4,5,6])

>>> N = M.H * (M * M.H) ** -1

>>> N.evalf(4)
[-0.9444,  0.4444]
[-0.1111,  0.1111]
[ 0.7222, -0.2222]
>>> M * N
[1, 0]
[0, 1]
```

For full column rank, replace M with M.H, transpose the result, and simplify to get the following formula for the 'left' inverse:

```
>>> M = sy.Matrix(3, 2, [1,2,3,4,5,6])

>>> N = (M.H * M) ** -1 * M.H

>>> N.evalf(4)
[-1.333, -0.3333,  0.6667]
[ 1.083,  0.3333, -0.4167]
>>> N * M
[1, 0]
[0, 1]
```